# R - shiny's downloadHandler() returns an empty HTML file if a condition is not met

Tags: r, if-statement, button, shiny, download

I want users to download a file from my shiny app. However, if they don't input correctly certain parameters inside a `textInput()` widget (e.g. a correct e-mail), I want to stop the download and display a notification (through the use of the functionalities of `shinyjs` for example).

However, if I put an `if` statement inside the `content` argument of `downloadHandler()`, if the condition is not met, the button fires the download anyway, but the result is just an **empty HTML file reporting a 404 error**. I've slightly modified the Shiny example showing the use of `downloadHandler()` to report this behaviour:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  textInput(input = "text",
            label = "Write 'download' to download the correct file"),
  
  br(),
  
  downloadButton(outputId = "downloadData",
                 label = "Download")
  
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- mtcars
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {
      
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
      
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      
      if (input$text == "download") {
        
        write.csv(x = data,
                  file =  file)
        
      }
      
    }
    
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Two scenarios will possibly solve the problem:

a) avoid the download of the HTML file reporting the error;
b) display a notification that does not constantly update each time I write something wrong in the text input until the right text is added.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You could avoid the problem by only enabling the download handler if the conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput(input = "text",
            label = "Write 'download' to download the correct file"),
  br(),
  downloadButton(outputId = "downloadData", label = "Download")
)

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- mtcars
  
  observeEvent(input$text, {
    if (input$text == "download") {
      enable("downloadData")
    } else {
      disable("downloadData")
    }
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
        write.csv(x = data, file =  file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Giving

[image]

and

[image]

[Note the change in font colour on the Download widget.]

**Edit**

In response to OP's request in the comments below, to use the shinyFeedback package...

1. Load the package and add the necessary call to the UI definition:

```
...
library(shinyFeedback)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  useShinyFeedback(), ...
```

2. Modify the `observeEvent` that watches the `textInput`:

```
  observeEvent(input$text, {
    if (input$text == "download") {
      hideFeedback("text")
      enable("downloadData")
      showFeedbackSuccess("text", "Ready to download")
    } else {
      disable("downloadData")
      showFeedbackDanger("text", "Please enter the password")
    }
  })
```

This gives

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer Limey! I thought about this solution, but the "problem" (if we can call it a real problem) is just that I want a message to appear if something is input wrongly by the user. For example, if a user types an email without specifying any "@" and then presses the download button, I want the warning message to appear. In contrast, if the button stays disabled, it is more tricky to fire the popup of the message saying "please enter a valid email address" at a specific moment.

Do you know a way to show the message correctly by using your solution? Thanks again

Comment: Your solution works great if the button is a generic actionButton(), but with the downloadHandler() things work a bit different since it is an "output" object, and not an "input" one.

Comment: One solution to my problem would be to let the warning note to appear, but then avoid to letting it appear every time the users delete (or add) one new character to the textInput(), but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: In that case, the `shinyFeedback` package may be of interest.  The additional context would have been helpful in your original post... :=)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. shinyFeedback indeed did the trick and works perfectly for this case. I've just slightly edited the last part of my question. If you edit your answer adding the shinyFeedback tip, I can mark it as accepted! Thanks a lot